# Ubuntu 14.04 + libvirt KVM, 3 physical nic, 3 external ip, 3 subnet + internal network HOW?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, kvm-virtualization

i have an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server with 3 nic, 3 external ip from 3 different subnet with 3 different gateway.

I have installed libvirt KVM and two Windows 7 64-bit guests.

The eth0 (1.1.1.1 with gateway 1.1.1.254) is the Ubuntu host (and a tun0 OpenVPN).
The br1-eth1 (2.2.2.2 with gateway 2.2.2.254) is the Win7-1 guest and
the br2-eth2 (3.3.3.3 with gateway 3.3.3.254) is the Win7-2 guest.

### /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 1.1.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 1.1.1.254
    dns-nameservers 8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8

auto br1
iface br1 inet manual
    bridge_ports eth1
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_hello 2
    bridge_maxage 12
    bridge_stp off

auto br2
iface br2 inet manual
    bridge_ports eth2
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_hello 2
    bridge_maxage 12
    bridge_stp off
```

### win7-1.xml

```
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='52:54:00:aa:aa:aa'/>
  <source bridge='br1'/>
  <target dev='vnet1'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <alias name='net0'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

### win7-2.xml

```
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='52:54:00:ba:ba:ba'/>
  <source bridge='br2'/>
  <target dev='vnet2'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <alias name='net0'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

I have set the eth1 and eth2 external ip in Windows guests.

The network is ok and working (the config is ok?), but i want to create an internal network between the Ubuntu host and the two Windows guest.
I want to access the Ubuntu host from Windows guests with 192.168.0.1 and the guests from host with 192.168.0.2 (Win7-1) and 192.168.0.3 (Win7-3).

I can manage the guests with virsh command and edit the libvirt xml file only.

Please give me the correct /etc/network/interfaces and host xmls for this internal network config!

Thank you very much!